# A way to migrate RabbitMQ exchanges from one vhost to another

Tags: rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, is there an easy/simple way to migrate the custom exchanges with bindings and queues from one Vhost to Another. (Vhost:dev to Vhost:stage)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version `3.6.1`is possible to [Export/import config on virtual host level](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/issues/65).

It is not possible to export one specific Exchange.

But you can take the Exchange defition through the [`HTTP API`](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_1/priv/www/api/index.html)

Using :
`http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source`

for example:
`http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my_company/bindings/source`

you will get a json like:

```
[
{
source: "my_company",
vhost: "/",
destination: "amq.gen-yZGNV22TwLcP3K-X69Yjyw",
destination_type: "queue",
routing_key: "#",
arguments: { },
properties_key: "%23"
},
{
source: "my_company",
vhost: "/",
destination: "my.queue",
destination_type: "queue",
routing_key: "#",
arguments: { },
properties_key: "%23"
}
]
```